# HTML5 Canvas DrawImage Safari 12.0 bug (tested on iOS 12.1/Mac OS Mojave)

Tags: html, canvas, safari, html5-canvas, mobile-safari

Found this bug recently while dealing with `CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage()` method of the Canvas 2D API

```
void ctx.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sWidth, sHeight, dx, dy, dWidth, dHeight);
```

[image]

The `sx` and `sy` parameters which are supposed to be the `x-axis` and `y-axis` coordinates of the *top-left corner* of the sub-rectangle of the **source image**, to draw into the destination context. (source: [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)) work differently on Safari browsers when provided with a value **less than 0** (negative values).

Negative values for `sx` and `sy`on other browsers (*tested Chrome and Microsoft Edge*) work as expected, by re-positioning the mentioned top-left corner along the negative sides of the `x-axis` and `y-axis`

[image]

---

But on **Safari**, negative values for `sx` and `sy` reset the top left coordinates to `0,0` and affect the `RIGHT BOTTOM CORNER` of the sub-rectangle of the **source image**, to draw into the destination context.

[image]

This is how the attached demo snippet of canvas renders on Chrome and Safari *(outline being the boundary of the canvas)*:
[image]

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const image = document.getElementById('source');

onload = e =>
  ctx.drawImage(image, -40, -160, 300, 290, 0, 0, 300, 290);
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="290"></canvas>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="source" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS35G.jpg">
</div>
```

Any work around for this will definitely help.

EDIT: Source width and source height doesn’t exceed the actual image’s width or height.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cropping with drawImage not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35500999/cropping-with-drawimage-not-working-in-safari)

Comment: Kaiido, No its not. Source width and source height doesn’t exceed the actual image’s width or height.

Comment: @Kaiido Also, it doesn't answer my question. I need that specific behavior, (blank space from top and left side of the canvas) which seems to work on all browsers except Safari. You should remove this possible duplicate flag.

Comment: @saibbyweb that is the same old bug in Safari's implementation of drawImage. Ok, you don't take it from the same exact angle as the proposed dupe, but the root cause is exactly the same, and the solution is too: calculate yourself the offset you need so that your source rect be entirely in the source image (i.e no negative x or y values). In your case it would be `ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 260, 130, 40, 160, 260, 130);`. So you are right your source rectangle is not bigger than the source image, but as in the proposed dupe, it is outside and non-existing pixels are being selected.

Comment: This is what fixes the problem. Thanks.The question marked as duplicate doesn't exactly solve the same problem as mine. There you have mentioned that due to some specific criteria the render is failing which clearly is not the case here. My `source height and width` <= `image height and image width` + you have also claimed `...Safari has a bug where when you try to draw non-existent pixels (out of the boundaries or the source image), it will just fail.` No, it doesn't fail unless values of `sx` and `sy` are negative. It's fine for positive values.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have experienced.

My code was created based on Chrome

```js
  renderImage(ctx) {
    if (this.$$.source) {
      const { image } = ... // html img tag with src

      const { viewport } = this.$$;
      ctx.drawImage(
        image,
        viewport.x,
        viewport.y,
        viewport.width,
        viewport.height,
        0,
        0,
        this.canvasWidth,
        this.canvasHeight
      );
    }
```

- viewport(x, y, width,height) - partial area of img to be rendered
- 0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight - canvas area

The code works well in chrome, but not in safari

Workaround is to offset destination dimension if sx or sy is negative

```js
  renderImage(ctx) {
    if (this.$$.source) {
      const { image } = ... // html img tag with src

      const { viewport } = this.$$;
      const offsetX = viewport.x < 0 ? -viewport.x : 0;
      const offsetY = viewport.y < 0 ? -viewport.y : 0;

      ctx.drawImage(
        image,
        viewport.x + offsetX, // set sx to 0 if negative
        viewport.y + offsetY, // set sy to 0 if negative
        viewport.width,
        viewport.height,
        offsetX, // shift dx if negative
        offsetY, // shift dy if negative
        this.canvasWidth,
        this.canvasHeight
      );
    }
```

It works in chrome and safari.

### My test image(400px, 400px)

[image]

### Chrome

- vieport=(x: -100, y:-100, width:400, height: 400)

[image]

### Safari

- vieport=(x: -100, y:-100, width:400, height: 400)

[image]