# Render Issues with custom style in OpenLayers and Safari Browser

Tags: html5-canvas, openlayers

I have noticed rendering issues with a simple custom render function, code below.

I render the geometry and some Text. I can see the Text but not the Geometry itself, expect if I zoom in very close. Any idea what is causing this visual error? I'm using OL v7.2.2 and iPhone 13 Mini iOS 16.1.1

This code works on any other Browser on a Windows Machine, and this works also if I use a Style Object (style: new Style({fill: new Fill...

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/of6nvtbk/22/

Relevant Code:

```
const interactionLayer = new ol.layer.VectorImage({
    source: featureSource,
    zIndex: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
    style: (feature, resolution) => {
      return new ol.style.Style({
        renderer: (pxGeometry, state) => {

          const polygon = new ol.geom.Polygon(pxGeometry);

          const olContext = ol.render.toContext(state.context);

          olContext.setFillStrokeStyle(
            new ol.style.Fill({
              color: "rgba(255,255,0, 1)",
            }),
            new ol.style.Stroke({
              color: "#000",
            }),
          );

          olContext.drawGeometry(polygon);
        },
      });
    },
  });
```

Iphone Screenshots while zooming in:

[image: zoom 1]

[image: zoom 2]

[image: zoom 3]

Edit:

Works without using drawGeometry:

```
ctx.beginPath();

ctx.moveTo(pxGeometry[0][0][0], pxGeometry[0][0][1]);

for (let i = 1; i < pxGeometry[0].length; i++) {
    ctx.lineTo(pxGeometry[0][i][0], pxGeometry[0][i][1]);
}
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

Comment: Perhaps a problem with drawing your style context to the layer context?  You could try applying the patch in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35503829/10118270

Comment: I'm not sure. Found out if I draw to canvas directly it works, see my edit